# Bat file works manually but not from python subprocess call

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess

I was trying to start/stop netsh trace in Windows10. Created a python and bat file to do the same.

When I try .bat file manually in command prompt it is working but not working using python subprocess call.

Python code:

```
 subprocess.call([r'C:\Tools\Netsh\startTrace.bat'])
```

Bat File:

```
netsh trace start persistent=yes capture=yes tracefile=C:\Netsh\nettrace.etl
```

Any suggestion on the next step are welcome

Comment: 'not working' is not a reasonable statement to make to people who are not sat in front of your computer. Please explain exactly what happens, and exactly what you're expecting to happen. This should require debugging information, screen output, error messages etc.

Comment: `Netsh` is an executable.  Why wouldn't you just execute that from your python script?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

subprocess.call((r"C:\Tools\Netsh\startTrace.bat") shell = True)
or
subprocess.Popen...